# Problem while Mocking BindingProvider and generated stub classes

Tags: java, junit, mocking

> I am using JAX-WS webservice generated classes or we can say the proxy
>   and stubs. I need to cast that proxy to the BindingProvider interface,
>   to set endpoint at runtime. (Unfortunately the generated proxy
>   interface does not extend the BindingProvider interface). I was able
>   to run the code but in Junit I am not able to mock the same. Sharing
>   the code below

```
  String url="http://<soapservice>?.wsdl"
  SomeInterface port = someImplService.getSomeImplPort();
  BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
  bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);
  port.methodcall();


  I am trying to mock the service in Junit

  @Mock BindingProvider bp;
  @Mock SomeInterface someInterface;
  @Mock SomeImplService someImplService;
  @Mock Map<String, Object> context;

   First Try:
   when(this.someImplService.getSomeImplPort()).thenReturn(bp);
   when(bp.getRequestContext()).thenReturn(context);
   when(context.put(anyObject(), anyObject())).thenReturn(context);
   someInterface.methodcall();

   For above code first line compile error as it expect reference of SomeInterface

   Second Try:
   when(this.someImplService.getSomeImplPort()).thenReturn(someInterface);
   when((BindingProvider)someInterface).thenReturn(bp);
   when(bp.getRequestContext()).thenReturn(context);
   when(context.put(anyObject(), anyObject())).thenReturn(context);
   someInterface.methodcall();

   For above code ClassCast Exception at line 2


   Can someone suggest me solution how to mock the binding provider and impl classes in this case
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem got solved by using:
someInterface=mock(SomeInterface.class,withSettings().extraInterfaces(BindingProvider.class));